# How to debug Tomcat compression issue?

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have two tomcat servers on two different CentOS machines running the same application (my dev environment and my test environment). One of them had compression enabled in its `server.xml` and the other had not, so I added the same configuration to the tomcat which hadn't compression enabled.

The relevant part of `server.xml` on both of the machines looks like this:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           compression="on" 
           compressionMinSize="2048" 
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" 
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,application/json,text/plain"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Before I enabled the compression I could call both applications with Postman from my local machine with no problem (only the second response wasn't compressed)

Now that compression is enabled, when I call the second application (where I enabled compression) I get an error:

> ```
> Content-Encoding Error (content_encoding_error) 
>
> Server response could not be decoded using encoding type returned by server.
> This is typically caused by a Web Site presenting a content encoding
> header of one type, and then encoding the data differently.
> ```

I made several observations:

- Both servers have the exact same configuration (at least I am pretty sure of that) and the first application works flawlessly.
- If I call the second application with a curl command on a Unix box I get the response with no problem. (But it doesn't work with postman from a Windows box)
- The response from the second application doesn't have the header `Content-Encoding`
- The logs don't show anything work (all the requests are logged as processed with status 200, but postman show a 502 error)
- The working application runs on tomcat `7.0.64` and the one not working on tomcat `7.0.76` but I haven't found anything related in the [changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html) between these versions.

So I am pretty puzzled as to why one server would work and not the other.

What can I check to try to find where the error comes from?

Comment: With postman you shoule be able to see exactly what the server returned to you - including all headers and so on.Did you check startup log of changed tomcat for any output?

Comment: @Jan Yes my startup logs don't show anything wrong. Postman shows the headers of the response (that's how I can say that I don't get the `Content-Encoding` header) but it looks like it can't read the response body (which makes sens if it can't decompress it)

Comment: you do send accept-encoding headers to both servers, right? Did you check if compression="force" changes something?

Comment: @Jan I send `Accept` headers to both servers. I just tried adding `Accept-Encoding` and the result is the same (The working server still works fine, the other one still doesn't work). Indeed I had already checked if `compression="force"` changes something but it doesn't

Comment: There seems to be an issue with posman an application/gzip: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2622

Comment: @DrHopfen Actually the issue is not related to Postman because I reproduce it with my client application (which is a cordova based application). (Also the issue you linked to was cause by the user encoding twice their data)

Comment: I see that you checked the changelog, even though, have you tried to install the same tomcat that it is working? Maybe you stumble in a non documented bug/issue for that non working version.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I found [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789) My JVM version is `1.8.0_161`, I am trying with another version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem came from the JDK version I was using (`1.8.0.161`) which contains a bug reported [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789), at least I think it was the same bug...

The servers didn't have the same version installed so I solved my problem by installing the working JDK of the server 1 to the server 2.